# Bash_profile code

Tags: bash, nvm

When I installed NVM it added a couple lines of code to my bash_profile. I understand that it adds the .nvm directory to my $PATH but I have no idea how it does so.

Could someone explain how the following works to me?

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/darcys22/.nvm"

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Comment: This sets the environment variable `NVM_DIR` (within this script) to be the path to the hidden `.nvm` directory. It then checks to see if the shell script `nvm.sh` exists in that diretory and, if it does (`&&`) executes it in the current shell (using `.`) if it does. Whatever else happens is all inside `/home/darcys22/.nvm/nvm.sh`. If you want to know more, you'd need to reveal the contents of that file. If your `PATH` changes after running this, then that's happening inside `nvm.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PATH before = is a variable name so the variable NVM_DIR equals the path /home/darcys22/.nvm (nvm prefixed with a dot, means its a hidden directory)

The square brackets contain a test, and with the -s it checks to see if the file /home/darcy22/nvm.sh exists and has a filesize greater than 0.

The space between the opening square bracket and the -s and again before the closing bracket are required.

[Read further](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)